# Nokogiri not reading/parsing structure of HTML file in CentOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, nokogiri, libxml2

I've written a script to parse out some needed code in HTML files that are uploaded to our app.  On OS X, this process works fine.  However, when I upload to our testing server, it doesn't.  When I go into the console on the test server and attempt to parse the file, Nokogiri won't see the structure - each time I get a single line of output instead of the whole document structure.  The rest of my script isn't being executed because Nokogiri isn't traversing the document.  Looking for some help on how to resolve the issue.

Here's the requisite code I'm using to open the file and feed it to Nokogiri:

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML(File.open("index.html", "r"))
```

Here's what html equates to:

```
#<Nokogiri::HTML::Document:0x10d9bbf0 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::DTD:0x10d9b81c name="html">]>
```

In OS X, I get the entire tree, as expected.

Here's the contents of index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="zero.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body class="fullpage-vert" onunload="javascript:clearInterval(audioLoop);">
<div id="container">
    <div id="danceHolder">
        <img id="danceVid" src="1-1.jpg" width="320" height="480" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="introHolder">
        <img id="introVid" src="0-1.jpg" width="320" height="480" alt="" />
        <div id="ctabg"></div>
        <div id="cta1"></div>
        <div id="cta2"></div>
        <div id="cta3"></div>
        <div id="phone"></div>
        <div id="logo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="mmbridge:*">bridge test</a>
<frameset cols="25%,75%">
   <frame src="frame_a.htm" />
   <frame src="frame_b.htm" />
</frameset>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try and search for the frameset, for example, I get nothing:

```
html.css("frameset").size
0
```

I know Nokogiri has problems with the default Libxml2 version installed on CentOS (2.6.2), but I've followed the instructions to get it built on a new version (2.7.8).  Here's the output for nokogiri -v:

```
# Nokogiri (1.5.0)
    --- 
    warnings: []

    nokogiri: 1.5.0
    ruby: 
      version: 1.9.2
      platform: x86_64-linux
      description: ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-linux]
      engine: ruby
    libxml: 
      binding: extension
      compiled: 2.7.8
      loaded: 2.7.8
```

Has anyone else seen behavior like this?

Comment: While I am sure this is an entirely unhelpful statement, I just ran your example in Ubuntu and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, swapping

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML(File.open("index.html", "r"))
```

for

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML(File.read("index.html"))
```

works, although now it won't calculate line numbers properly (everything is line number 0).

Comment: Note that with your previous code you were leaving a file handle dangling. You should instead try: `html = File.open(file,'r'){ |f| Nokogiri.HTML(f) }`

Comment: Are the line endings in the file all "\n" ?

Comment: @JohnDouthat - not sure.  It's an HTML file, so I'm assuming so. What's the easiest way to check?  Just output the parsed file as a string?